# Combobox visual style

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am trying to change the appearance of the combobox from the one on the left to the one on the right on the below image.
[image: combobox ui styles]

Just to be clear, I am talking about how the combobox on the right looks like it's sticking out while the one on the left looks like a text box. The contents of the comboboxes in the image are not relevant.

Edit: Here is an image of what my DropDownList(1) and DropDown(2) styles look like.

[image: combobox ui styles]

Comment: Are these WinForms? Those controls have different behaviors. The one on the left has `.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDown` and allows typing text. The one on the right has `.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList` and only allows picking a displayed item.

Comment: If this is WinForms it would be good to add an appropriate tag.

Comment: I added an image of what my DropDownList and DropDown styles look like. As you can tell neither look like the box on the right in the first image.

Comment: Looks like that image came from [A ComboBox Control With Grouping](https://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/104), published in June 2010, so I'm guessing you are looking at the Windows Vista or Windows 7 visual styles.

Comment: This is one of those controls with old roots, so it's going to look different depending upon the Windows edition it's running on.

Comment: Running this on Windows 10, no way to have it look better?

Comment: You can customize these things easier in WPF.